# How to terminate persistent connection in axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, keep-alive

I'm working on the project which needs to establish a persistent connection with web-server. I'm planning to use axios like this.

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://httpbin.org/headers',
  headers: { 'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar' },
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
    keepAlive: true,
  }),
});

axiosInstance
  .get()
  .then((response) => console.log(response.headers))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

With the get call , the connection is established , but after some calculation or processing I need to break this persistent connection (on-demand basis), is there a way to do this in axios?

Also if this instance of axios `axiosInstance` gets deleted (the reference of this object goes out of scope and the GC reclaims the memory consumed by it) , will the keep-alive or persistent connection automatically ends with server?